# mysql search title, description and multi rows tag

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

i have following tables.

the entry table describe

```
+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) unsigned  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(255)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| slug        | varchar(255)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(10) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| unsafe      | enum('0','1')     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| copyright   | enum('0','1')     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| status      | enum('0','1','2') | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| date_add    | datetime          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the tags table describe

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| relation_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

i want search in entry.title and tag.name. How can the performance for this query.

i continue usign fulltext. How do you ?

Comment: You can use an union: 1-st query with fulltext for the title; 2-nd  query join's tags and uses a `tag.name IN('tag1','tag2'..)`. Assuming you want a full word match for the tags.

Comment: vatev thanks for your answer. you can write any sample query in answer to ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to make sure both the title and name fields are indexed (not able to see that with the information you sent.  I assume that tag.relation_id relates to entry.id. SO you could search like:

```
SELECT * FROM entry as e JOIN tags as t on e.id = t.relation_id WHERE e.title LIKE('%YOURSEARCH%') OR t.name LIKE('%YOURSEARCH%')
```

Comment: it does not look very good. if match a tag i want up to search results. or match title i want down search results

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the tags relate to the entries, so I'm going to assume the relation_id is the entry id.

```
SELECT 
    e.*
FROM entry e
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('{search string}')
{maybe a limit and/or order here}
UNION
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    e.*
FROM entry e
JOIN tags t ON t.relation_id = e.id
WHERE t.name IN ('word1','word2',...)#{search string} split by whitespace
{maybe a limit and/or order here}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean is to show the attributes the columns `entry . title` and `tag . name` by joining `entry . user_id` into `tag . relation_id`? If that's what you want, you could check the SQL queries below:

```
SELECT entry . title , tag . name
FROM entry
INNER JOIN tag ON entry . user_id = tag . relation_id
ORDER BY entry . title
```

Now if you're using query string to search a value on `entry . title` and `tag . name` attributes, try to check this code:

```
$q = $_GET["q"];

$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT entry . title , tag . name
FROM entry
INNER JOIN tag ON entry . user_id = tag . relation_id
WHERE entry . title LIKE "%' . $q . '%"
OR tag . name LIKE "%' . $q . '%"');
```

Example, when a searcher go to *domain.com/?q=test* the system will then look if there's a matched text for **test** on `entry . title` and `tag . name` and if ever founds some, the row*(s)* of `entry . title` and `tag . name` that included that word will be a result.

Now if you want to show all the attributes that included the value of the query string *?q=* then just `SELECT *`. Check this out:

```
$q = $_GET["q"];

$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT *
FROM entry
INNER JOIN tag ON entry . user_id = tag . relation_id
WHERE entry . title LIKE "%' . $q . '%"
OR tag . name LIKE "%' . $q . '%"');
```

Or include all there `TableName . AttributeField`s manually, such this:

```
$q = $_GET["q"];

$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT entry . id , entry . title , entry . slug , entry . description , entry . user_id , entry . copyright , entry . status , tag . id , tag . relation_id , tag . name
FROM entry
INNER JOIN tag ON entry . user_id = tag . relation_id
WHERE entry . title LIKE "%' . $q . '%"
OR tag . name LIKE "%' . $q . '%"');
```

---

P.S. don't forget to rename the **"tags"** table into **"tag"**.

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking for a system to search title and then narrow the result using tags. Is this what you are looking for?

To achieve this first display the results for title search and then have tags as the links 
something like this very page
"mysql search title, description and multi rows tag" is your title and in the results and in the result display tags as buttons " mysql search full-text-search " When clicked on tags show specific results.

If you could give more information or a scenario where & what you are trying to achieve, would help us in getting you a better solution.

Comment: And also dont forget to add index keys to title & tags, to increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT entries.id, entries.title
FROM entries
INNER JOIN tags ON entries.id = tags.relation_id
WHERE tags.name IN ("tag1", "tag2", "tag3") AND MATCH(entries.title, entries.description) AGAINST ('{text}')
```