# mysql search title, description and multi rows tag (regarding conditions)

Tags: php, mysql, search, tags, conditional-statements

I want to realize a search similar to [mysql search title, description and multi rows tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674232/mysql-search-title-description-and-multi-rows-tag).

Here are my tables:

**Books**:

```
+----+-----------------------+-------------+
| id | name                  | description | 
+----+-----------------------+-------------+
|  1 | Me Before You         | [TEXT]      |
|  2 | How To Win Friends... | [TEXT]      |
|  3 | The Girl on the Train | [TEXT]      |
|  4 | After You             | [TEXT]      |
|  5 | We Were Liars         | [TEXT]      |
+----+-----------------------+-------------+
```

**Tags**:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id | tag                   |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | romance               |
|  2 | thriller              |
|  3 | fantasy               |
|  4 | science fiction       |
|  5 | drama                 |
|  6 | friends               |
+----+-----------------------+
```

**Books_tags**:

```
+---------+--------+
| book_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |
|       1 |      3 |
|       2 |      3 |
|       3 |      3 |
|       3 |      5 |
|       4 |      1 |
|       4 |      5 |
|       4 |      6 |
|       5 |      2 |
|       5 |      6 |
+---------+--------+
```

Here are some example searches and the desired results:

```
'romance'       -> books 1, 4
'friends'       -> books 2, 4, 5
'friends win'   -> books 2
'fantasy'       -> books 2, 3
'fantasy train' -> books 3
```

Before building the SQL query, a function checks every given keyword if it's even a tag at once. My problem is, for example, in this case:

- Case: 3 /
- Keywords: friends win /
- Tags: friends

Query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    b.id, b.name, 
    MATCH(b.name) AGAINST('*friends* *win*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as name_score,
    MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST('friends' IN BOOLEAN MODE)as tag_score
FROM 
    books b
LEFT JOIN 
    books_tags bt ON bt.book_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN 
    tags t ON t.id = bt.tag_id 
WHERE  
    MATCH(b.name) AGAINST('*friends win*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST('friends' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY 
    b.id
ORDER BY 
    name_score DESC, (tag_score + name_score) DESC
```

Results:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '4' (length=1)
  2 => string '5' (length=1)
```

In this case, the keyword 'friends' already matches the title, so the condition must be reduced and should not search the tags anymore. How can I solve it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve/avoid?

Comment: If a keyword already matches the title, the tag-condition `OR MATCH(t.tag) AGAINST('friends' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` must be ignored because the point is mood.

Comment: But so what? Why does it matter? Performance?

Comment: No. It's all about the result. If a keyword matches the title, it's obsolete for the tags and must not be included to the search-condition. In my example, the results are the books 2, 4 and 5, but it must be only book 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I wrote a function, that generates a working query for me. The function is very complex and depends on several user inputs. **The solution is to concatenate t.tag and b.name**. This is, how my WHERE-condition looks like and it work's fine for me:

```
... WHERE ap.active='yes'
AND (LOWER(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(LENGTH(t.tag), t.tag, NULL), IF(LENGTH(b.name), b.name, NULL) )) REGEXP 'friends'
AND LOWER(CONCAT_WS(' ', IF(LENGTH(t.tag), t.tag, NULL), IF(LENGTH(b.name), b.name, NULL) )) REGEXP 'win')
GROUP BY b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?...

Data set

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books;

CREATE TABLE books
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
,FULLTEXT(name)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

INSERT INTO books VALUES
(1,'Me Before You'),
(2,'How To Win Friends...'),
(3,'The Girl on the Train'),
(4,'After You'),
(5,'We Were Liars');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tags;

CREATE TABLE tags
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,tag VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tags VALUES
(1,'romance'),
(2,'thriller'),
(3,'fantasy'),
(4,'science fiction'),
(5,'drama'),
(6,'friends');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books_tags;

CREATE TABLE books_tags
(book_id INT NOT NULL
,tag_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(book_id,tag_id)
);

INSERT INTO books_tags VALUES
(1,1),
(1,3),
(2,3),
(3,3),
(3,5),
(4,1),
(4,5),
(4,6),
(5,2),
(5,6);
```

Query and result

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
              , MATCH(b.name) AGAINST('*friends* *win*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) name_score
           FROM books b 
           LEFT 
           JOIN books_tags bt 
             ON bt.book_id = b.id 
           LEFT 
           JOIN tags t 
             ON t.id = bt.tag_id 
            AND t.tag IN ('friends','win') 
          WHERE t.id IS NULL;

+----+-----------------------+------------+
| id | name                  | name_score |
+----+-----------------------+------------+
|  1 | Me Before You         |          0 |
|  2 | How To Win Friends... |          1 |
|  3 | The Girl on the Train |          0 |
|  4 | After You             |          0 |
|  5 | We Were Liars         |          0 |
+----+-----------------------+------------+
```